# Fastest way to read an image from huge uncompressed tar file in __getitem__ of PyTorch custom dataset

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, pytorch, tarfile

I have a huge dataset (2 million) of jpg images in one uncompressed TAR file. I also have a txt file each line is the name of the image in TAR file in order.

```
img_0000001.jpg
img_0000002.jpg
img_0000003.jpg
...
```

and images in tar file are exactly the same.
I searched alot and find out `tarfile` module is the best one, but when I tried to read images from tar file using `name`, it takes too long. And the reason is, everytime I call `getmemeber(name)` method, it calls `getmembers()` method which scan whole tar file, then return a `Namespace` of all names, then start finding in this `Namespace`.

if it helps, my dataset size is 20GB single tar file.

I don't know it is better idea to first extract all then use extracted folders in my `CustomDataset` or reading directly from archive.

Here is the code I am using to read a single file from tar file:

```py
        with tarfile.open('data.tar') as tf:
            tarinfo = tf.getmember('img_000001.jpg')
            image = tf.extractfile(tarinfo)
            image = image.read()
            image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image))
```

I used this code in my `__getitem__` method of `CustomDataset` class that loops over all names in `filelist.txt`

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tarfile` seems to have caching for `getmember`, it reuses `getmembers()` results.

But if you use the provided snipped in `__getitem__`, then for each item from the dataset the tar file is open and read fully, one image file extracted, then the tar file closed and the associated info is lost.

The simplest way to resolve this is probably to open the tar file in your dataset's `__init__` like `self.tf = tarfile.open('data.tar')`, but then you need to remember to close it in the end.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I will try your idea and update my question.
One more question, why it won't work on multi thread processes? I mean if increase `num_workers` from 1 to any number.

Comment: Actually it should work with parallel reads. I'll delete that part from my answer.

Comment: I used your idea with some modifications. I called `tf.getmembers` method in __init__, then used `tf.extractfile` (or `tf.getmember` ) in `__getitem__` method. Thank you